# Cannot add or update a child row laravel 5.4 many to many relation

Tags: php, laravel

in many to many join i get this error :

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`laravel`.`posts_tag`, CONSTRAINT `posts_tag_tag_id_foreign` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`Tag_ID`) REFERENCES `Tag` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert
>   into `Posts_Tag` (`Posts_ID`, `Tag_ID`) values (26, Tag num 2))

my controller :

```
public function Share(Request $request)
{

    $posts = Posts::create($request->all());

    $posts->tags()->attach(Input::get('Tag'));

    return $posts;

    return Redirect()->back();

}
```

my model :

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'Posts_Tag', 'Posts_ID', 'Tag_ID');
}
```

view :

```
            {{ Form::open(array('url'=>'post')) }}

            {{ Form::label('Title') }} : {{ Form::text('Title') }}
            <br>
            {{ Form::label('Content') }} : {{ Form::textarea('Content') }}
            <br>
            {{ Form::label('Tag :') }}
            <select name="Tag" id="Tag" class="Tag">
                @foreach($tag as $tag)
                    <option>{{ $tag->Tag }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
            {{ Form::submit('Share Post') }}

            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: Please work on your caps and grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not passing any tag id, fill the option's value

```
<select name="tags" id="Tag" class="Tag">
                //tags is a better name for collection of tgas
       @foreach($tags as $tag)
              <option value='{{$tag->id}}'>{{ $tag->Tag }}</option>
       @endforeach
</select>
```

And in your controller

```
$post->tags()->attach($request->tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use actual tag names with `attach()`. Because you're passing name instead of ID, you need to get tag ID first:

```
$post = Posts::create($request->all());
$tagId = Tag::where('name', $request->tag)->value('id');
$post->tags()->attach(tagId);
```